# syntax error in javascript inside asp page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            /* <![CDATA[ */
            var on_id = 1;

     if (<%=GetValue() %>) {
                on_id  = <%=GetValue() %>; 
            }
   </script>
```

I do get 2 syntax errors: at the 2nd closed brachet: after `%>` and at `;` after again `%>`. `GetValue()` is a public decimal method defined in code behind.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: that `<![CDATA[` thingy looks suspicious.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Its part of the asp code.. Ads it automatically if I am not mistaken

Comment: Try removing it from your code and running it once as well, apart from removing it from question

Comment: Why not use a AJAX call??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not an expert but i had faced a similar problem.it got solved by putting <%=GetValue() %> in ''(single quotes) i.e '<%=GetValue() %>' so i stopped getting syntax errors

use parseFloat() function to get the float value from the string

Comment: i dont think it matters.did you try running it. debug it on the browser and see if its working.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'yoururl/GetValue',
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
     success: successFunction,
    error: errorFunction
    });
```

Do it using an AJAX call :)Check the condition in successhandler

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var on_id = 1;
        <%if (GetValue()) {%>
            on_id  = '<%=GetValue() %>'; 
        <%}%>
   </script>
```